# elasticsearch not initializing on windows 10

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jvm

I am running elasticsearch 2.3.5 on windows 10 in a standalone mode [not as a service]. The instance suddenly started hanging in the initialization phase without any listener on port 9200. I am using jre1.8.0_111. I explicitly enabled ports 9200 and 9300 on my firewall settings but that did not help either

Here are the logs for the same having enabled debug logs

```
[2017-01-17 12:35:52,183][DEBUG][bootstrap                ] console control handler receives event [0@0]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,076][DEBUG][bootstrap                ] windows/Kernel32 library loaded
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,080][DEBUG][bootstrap                ] Windows ActiveProcessLimit initialization successful
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,081][DEBUG][bootstrap                ] console ctrl handler correctly set
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,084][DEBUG][bootstrap                ] java.class.path: D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/commons-cli-1.3.1.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/compiler-0.8.13.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/compress-lzf-1.0.2.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/guava-18.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/HdrHistogram-2.1.6.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/hppc-0.7.1.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jackson-core-2.6.6.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.6.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jackson-dataformat-smile-2.6.6.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.6.6.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/joda-convert-1.2.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/joda-time-2.9.4.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jts-1.13.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-analyzers-common-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-backward-codecs-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-core-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-grouping-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-highlighter-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-join-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-memory-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-misc-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-queries-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-queryparser-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-sandbox-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-spatial-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-spatial3d-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-suggest-5.5.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/securesm-1.0.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/snakeyaml-1.15.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/spatial4j-0.5.jar;D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/t-digest-3.0.jar
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,085][DEBUG][bootstrap                ] sun.boot.class.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\classes
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,087][DEBUG][bootstrap                ] classloader urls: [file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/commons-cli-1.3.1.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/compiler-0.8.13.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/compress-lzf-1.0.2.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/elasticsearch-2.3.5.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/guava-18.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/HdrHistogram-2.1.6.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/hppc-0.7.1.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jackson-core-2.6.6.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.6.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jackson-dataformat-smile-2.6.6.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.6.6.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jna-4.1.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/joda-convert-1.2.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/joda-time-2.9.4.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/jts-1.13.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-analyzers-common-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-backward-codecs-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-core-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-grouping-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-highlighter-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-join-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-memory-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-misc-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-queries-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-queryparser-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-sandbox-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-spatial-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-spatial3d-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/lucene-suggest-5.5.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/netty-3.10.5.Final.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/securesm-1.0.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/snakeyaml-1.15.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/spatial4j-0.5.jar, file:/D:/tools/elasticsearch-2.3.5/lib/t-digest-3.0.jar]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,090][DEBUG][bootstrap                ] java.home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,255][INFO ][node                     ] [Ion] version[2.3.5], pid[19160], build[90f439f/2016-07-27T10:36:52Z]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,256][INFO ][node                     ] [Ion] initializing ...
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,256][DEBUG][node                     ] [Ion] using config [D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5\config], data [[D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5\data]], logs [D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5\logs], plugins [D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5\plugins]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,282][DEBUG][bootstrap                ] java.home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,951][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Ion] modules [reindex, lang-expression, lang-groovy], plugins [], sites []
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,966][DEBUG][env                      ] [Ion] using node location [[NodePath{path=D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5\data\elasticsearch\nodes\0, spins=null}]], local_node_id [0]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,968][DEBUG][env                      ] [Ion] node data locations details:
 -> D:\tools\elasticsearch-2.3.5\data\elasticsearch\nodes\0, free_space [803.7gb], usable_space [803.7gb], total_space [931.3gb], spins? [unknown], mount [DATADRIVE1 (D:)], type [NTFS]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,969][INFO ][env                      ] [Ion] heap size [910.5mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,977][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [force_merge], type [fixed], size [1], queue_size [null]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,983][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [percolate], type [fixed], size [8], queue_size [1k]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,992][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [fetch_shard_started], type [scaling], min [1], size [16], keep_alive [5m]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,993][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [listener], type [fixed], size [4], queue_size [null]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,994][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [index], type [fixed], size [8], queue_size [200]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,995][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [refresh], type [scaling], min [1], size [4], keep_alive [5m]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,995][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [suggest], type [fixed], size [8], queue_size [1k]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,995][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [generic], type [cached], keep_alive [30s]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,997][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [warmer], type [scaling], min [1], size [4], keep_alive [5m]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,997][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [search], type [fixed], size [13], queue_size [1k]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,998][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [flush], type [scaling], min [1], size [4], keep_alive [5m]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,998][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [fetch_shard_store], type [scaling], min [1], size [16], keep_alive [5m]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,999][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [management], type [scaling], min [1], size [5], keep_alive [5m]
[2017-01-17 12:36:03,999][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [get], type [fixed], size [8], queue_size [1k]
[2017-01-17 12:36:04,000][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [bulk], type [fixed], size [8], queue_size [50]
[2017-01-17 12:36:04,000][DEBUG][threadpool               ] [Ion] creating thread_pool [snapshot], type [scaling], min [1], size [4], keep_alive [5m]
[2017-01-17 12:36:04,826][DEBUG][monitor.jvm              ] [Ion] enabled [true], interval [1s], gc_threshold [{default=GcThreshold{name='default', warnThreshold=10000, infoThreshold=5000, debugThreshold=2000}, young=GcThreshold{name='young', warnThreshold=1000, infoThreshold=700, debugThreshold=400}, old=GcThreshold{name='old', warnThreshold=10000, infoThreshold=5000, debugThreshold=2000}}]
```

i've excluded bootstrap logs to meet the posting limits but they are primarily examining jar messages. Any ideas what's happening here?